# How to parse json when an attribute might have two types in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using same model to parse 2 json responses,

In one response an attribute `user` is string type, and in the other response `user` is an object.

How could I parse in this situation? I tried,

```
CampaignProductDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  user= json['user'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  data['user'] = this.user;
  return data;
}
```

But it shows _typeError when `user` is an object. How should I sort it out? Do I need to create a new model for this single attribute?

Comment: How have you defined your user variable? If it's defined as a String, you can't assign an object to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is` operator in Dart

```
CampaignProductDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   user= json['user'] == null ? null : (json['user'] is String ? json['user'] : this.user;
}
```

as an alternative, In Dart every object has a `runtimeType` instance member which returns type of object at runtime ( I wouldn't advice to use it on production, somewhere read that it is only for debugging purpose).